# Unable to select values in second column listview

Tags: vb.net, winforms, listview

I've a listview that dynamically populates values between two columns in this fashion:

```
column 1 | column 2
value1 | value 2
value3 | value 4
```

however I'm unable to select any values in column 2 - is there a property of the listview that's preventing me from doing this or is it the way I populate these columns? Here's my code to populate the column:

```
For k = 0 To UBound(tempValues)  

    Dim itm As New ListViewItem(tempValues(k))   

    If k Mod 2 = 0 Then 

        listview1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)  

        itm.SubItems.Add(tempValues(k + 1)) 

        listview1.Items.Add(itm)  

    End If 

    listview1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)  
Next
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The closest I can see for this is to set `listView1.FullRowSelect = true` (I assume you have `listView1.View = View.Details`?)

This however will only give you full row selecting - Remember the 2nd column represents the 1st Sub Item of the listview's items.

If you want multiple columns of data, you might be better off setting `listView1.View = View.Details = View.List`, which will cause it to wrap a single list of items onto multiple columns when it runs out of vertical space.

**Edit:**

If you use `listView1.View = View.List`, your population would need to change to the following:

```
For k = 0 To UBound(tempValues)  
    listview1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(tempValues(k))   
Next 

listview1.AutoResizeColumns(ColumnHeaderAutoResizeStyle.HeaderSize)
```

But it would mean you end up with the list like so:

```
Value 1
Value 2
Value 3
Value 4
```

And if ListView was made too short to display, all these, it would wrap them:

```
Value 1    Value 4
Value 2
Value 3
```

Comment: THanks for your reply.  If I was to go the listView1.View = View.Details = View.List route would I have to rework my logic on adding the items to the listview?  Or perhaps is there another way to not use subitems of items on the listview?  Is it possible to have mulitple items on a listview throughout different columns so I won't have to use the subitems?  I tried that code you suggested listView1.View = View.Details = View.List and it doesn't add the second column of entries.  Is there no way to select subitems in a listview?  THanks for all your help!

Comment: @Criel: Updated my answer with some more info.

Comment: That works great!  I suppose using the subitems would only be useful when displaying data and not interacting with it. Would there be a way to have this list option go horizontal and once it's out of room go to the next row and begin again?

Comment: @Criel: `listView1.View = View.SmallIcon` Gets as close as you can with a list view I think.